# Pyspark error accessing temp storage dir in Azure Blob

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, azure-synapse

I'm running in an Azure Synapse notebook and trying to use PySpark to read a SQL table.  It seems to be able to read the table, but when I want to show the results, I get an error indicating that it can't access the temporary directory.

If I specify the temp directory using the "wasbs" schema, I get this error:

*External file access failed due to internal error: 'Parameters provided to connect to the Azure storage account are not valid.*

If I specify the temp directory with the abfss schema, I get this error:

*CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS SELECT statement failed as the path name 'abfss://@.dfs.core.windows.net/temp/SQLAnalyticsConnectorStaging/...tbl' could not be used for export. Please ensure that the specified path is a directory which exists or can be created, and that files can be created in that directory*.

The container name, account name, and account key are correct, so I'm guessing that I'm not setting the config correctly, but I've tried everything I could think of.

I've also set "hadoop" config by replacing the "fs.azure.account.key" with "spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.key".

Code examples are below.  I think it's successfully accessing the database because I'm able to show the columns using print ("columns", df.columns).  I get the error when I try to show the data with print ("head", df.head())

Any help is appreciated.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

 

container = "container_name"
storage_account_name = "storage_account_name"
account_key = "account_key"
appName = "test"
master = "local"

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName(appName) \
    .master(master) \
    .getOrCreate()

spark.conf.set(f"fs.azure.account.key.{storage_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net", account_key)

df = spark.read \
  .option(Constants.TEMP_FOLDER, f"wasbs://{container}@{storage_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/temp") \
  .synapsesql("db_name.schema_name..spark_test")

print ("columns", df.columns)
print ("head", df.head())
```

Answer (score 0):

> *could not be used for export. Please ensure that the specified path is a directory which exists or can be created, and that files can be created in that directory*.

**PolyBase is unable to perform the operation, which results in this error.**

***Causes:***

- You encounter a network error when attempting to access the Azure blob storage on the necessary network ports.
- configuration the Azure storage account.

***Resolution:***

- Enable outbound traffic from CTL01 node over the supplied internet connectivity to *.blob.core.windows.net on local firewall **`ports 80 and 443`**.
- Verify that the storage account is set up as a standard storage account using either **`standard locally redundant storage (Standard-LRS) or standard geo-redundant storage (Standard-GRS)`** and configure the account for **`General Purpose`**.